# How to wait correctly for all async functions triggered in a sync loop to return a value - JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have an async operation in a loop which fetches a result and pushes to an array like this:

```js
arr = []

while (some_limit_reaches) {
  async_operation(arg, function(err, data) {
  if (!err)
    arr.push(data)
  })
}

// now arr is not completely filled until all async
// operations are finished in the loop above
```

the problem is that array is not completely filled until all async operations are done, how can I have a fully filled array after loop is over without using setTimeout?

Comment: if you found my answer useful would you consider to vote/accept my answer? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make a an asynchronous operation synchronous.  You need to check if your desired state is true in your asynchronous callback.  Try something like this.

```
while (some_limit_reaches) {
  async_operation(arg, function(err, data) {
  if (!err)
    arr.push(data);
    if(check_if_the_array_is_full){
      //Call some function that continues your operation
    }
  })
}
```

This way your processing won't continue until all the array is full.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little bit verbose, but respects the separation of tasks. Its schema is similar to kriskowal's `q.all`.

```
var arr = [], limit = 10, i=0, terminated_operations = 0;

while (i < limit) {
  async_operation(arg, function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    arr.push(data);
    operationTerminated(arr);
  }
  });
}

function operationTerminated(data) {
  terminated_operations++;
  if( terminated_operations === limit - 1) {
    doStuff(data);
    terminated_operations = 0;
  }
}

function doStuff(data) {
  console.log('all data returned', data);
}
```

The first snippet represents the core logic. The second function is only a trigger of the action declared in the third one.

**Edit:**

In order to answer at the original question in the title

> How can I make sure that an async operation does not keep array in my code empty?

I recommend to return `data=undefined` in case of `async_operation` failure, so you can accept also `[]` as valid return value and keep higher control in core logic. This way you can rewrite the loop as:

```
while (i < limit) {
  async_operation(arg, function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
    console.error('error occurred', err);
    break;
  }
  if(data) {
    arr.push(data);
    operationTerminated(arr);
  }
  });
}
```